# Creating a vscode snippet regex for file name

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am building  my own snippet in vscode.
I am not the best with regex so I was using chatgpt to help me build regex.
However, I am unable to create a regex that will convert my file name such as:

`AppInput.tsx` into `app-input`

Currently, I have this expression `TM_FILENAME_BASE/[^0-9a-z]+//gi` for converting my file name:

`AppInput.tsx` into `AppInput`

Looking for a solution.

Comment: is this a javascript regex question? If so, add the [tag:javascript] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on file names like `App.tsx`, `AppInput.tsx`., `AppInputMore.tsx`, etc. for any number of groups in the filename:

```
"modify FileName":{
  "scope": "typescriptreact",   // if you want to restrict to javascriptrect files
  "prefix": "case",             // whatever you want for a prefix
  "body": [
    "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)(?=([A-Z]?))/${1:/downcase}${2:+-}/g}",
  ]
}
```

`${2:+-}` is a conditional, only if there is a capture group 2 add the following `-`.

Comment: Thanks wors well, when putting it in a string "    ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)(?=([A-Z]?))/${1:/downcase}${2:+-}/g}" with a whitepace, I get this Invalid characters in string. Control characters must be escaped.jsonc(262) any ideas?

Comment: I'm nor sure what you mean by "when putting it in a string"?  It works as is in a snippet.  Are you using it in another way?  In some cases, various characters that have special meaning in a regex have to be escaped or even double-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variable

```
${TM_FILENAME/(.)([^A-Z]*)(.)([^.]*)\\.tsx/${1:/downcase}${2}-${3:/downcase}${4}/}
```